# Overlapping circle

Tags: code-golf, geometry, counting

You should write a program or function that given an `N` by `N` equally spaced square grid and a solid inscribed circle outputs or returns the number of grid squares which are overlapped partially or fully by the solid circle.

0-sized overlaps (i.e. when the circle only touches a line) are not counted. (These overlaps occur at e.g. `N = 10`.)

### Example

`N = 8 (64 squares), Slices = 60`

[image: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/3M1ekwY.png)]

### Input

- An integer `N > 0`. (The grid wil have `N * N` squares.)

### Output

- An integer, the number of solid circle slices.

### Examples

(input-output pairs)

```
Inputs:  1 2 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  11  12  13  14  15
Outputs: 1 4 9 16 25 36 45 60 77 88 109 132 149 172 201
```

This is code-golf so shortest entry wins.

Comment: Is it just me or is everyone missing the obvious solution here? **Edit:** Never mind. At first that looked like a simple `N^2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>27</s> 26

```
-*QQ*4lfgsm^d2T*QQ^%2_UtQ2
```

Try it online: [Pyth Compiler/Executor](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=-*QQ*4lfgsm%5Ed2T*QQ%5E%252_UtQ2&input=15&debug=0)

I use a `2Nx2N` grid and count overlapping `2x2` squares. That is a little bit shorter, since I already know the radius `N`.

And actually I don't count the overlapping squares. I count the non-overlapping squares of the second quadrant, multiply the number by 4 and subtract the result from `N*N`.

#### Explanation for the 27 solution:

```
-*QQ*4lfgsm^-Qd2T*QQ^t%2UQ2   implicit: Q = input()
                     t%2UQ    generates the list [2, 4, 6, ..., Q]
                    ^     2   Cartesian product: [(2, 2), (2, 4), ..., (Q, Q)]
                              These are the coordinates of the right-down corners
                              of the 2x2 squares in the 2nd quadrant. 
       f                      Filter the coordinates T, for which:
        gsm^-Qd2T*QQ             dist-to-center >= Q
                                 more detailed: 
          m     T                   map each coordinate d of T to:
           ^-Qd2                       (Q - d)^2
         s                          add these values
        g        *QQ                 ... >= Q*Q
    *4l                       take the length and multiply by 4
-*QQ                          Q*Q - ...
```

#### Explanation for the 26 solution:

I noticed that I use the coordinates only once and immediately subtract the coordinates from `Q`. Why not simply generate the values `Q - coords` directly?

This happens in `%2_UtQ`. Only one char larger than in the previous solution and saves 2 chars, because I don't have to substract `-Q`.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, 72

```python
lambda n:sum(n>abs(z%-~n*2-n+(z/-~n*2-n)*1j)for z in range(~n*~n))+n+n-1
```

Ungolfed:

```python
def f(n):
    s=0
    for x in range(n+1):
        for y in range(n+1):
            s+=(x-n/2)**2+(y-n/2)**2<(n/2)**2
    return s+n+n-1
```

The grid points for an `(n+1)*(n+1)` square. A cell overlaps the circle if its grid point nearest the center is inside the circle. So, we can count grid points, except this misses `2*n+1` grid points at axes (both for even and odd `n`), so we correct for that manually.

The code saves characters by using [complex distances](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41861/20260) to calculate the distance to the center and a [loop collapse](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41217/20260) to iterate over a single index.

Answer (score 7):

## CJam, <s>36 35 34</s> 27 bytes

This turned out to be the same algorithm as xnor's, but I wonder if there is any better one.

```
rd:R,_m*{{2*R(-_g-}/mhR<},,
```

**Code explanation**:

```
rd:R                                "Read the input as double and store it in R";
    ,_                              "Get 0 to input - 1 array and take its copy";
      m*                            "Get Cartesian products";
                                    "Now we have coordinates of top left point of each";
                                    "of the square in the N by N grid";
        {               },,         "Filter the squares which are overlapped by the";
                                    "circle and count the number";
         {        }/                "Iterate over the x and y coordinate of the top left";
                                    "point of the square and unwrap them";
          2*                        "Scale the points to reflect a 2N grid square";
            R(-                     "Reduce radius - 1 to get center of the square";
               _g-                  "Here we are reducing or increasing the coordinate";
                                    "by 1 in order to get the coordinates of the vertex";
                                    "of the square closer to the center of the grid";
                    mhR<            "Get the distance of the point from center and check";
                                    "if its less than the radius of the circle";
```

*UPDATE* : Using the 2N trick from Jakube along with some other techniques to save 7 bytes!

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=rd%3AR%2C_m*%7B%7B2*R(-_g-%7D%2FmhR%3C%7D%2C%2C&input=7)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth,  <del>44</del>  36

```
JcQ2L^-+b<bJJ2sm+>*JJ+y/dQy%dQqQ1*QQ
```

Trying to clean it a bit in case I could shave some bytes.

#### Explanation

```
                           Q = eval(input())    (implicit)
JcQ2                       calculate half of Q and store in J
L                          define function y(b) that returns
 ^-+b<bJJ2                 (b - J + (1 if b < J else 0)) ^ 2
s                          output sum of
 m                 *QQ      map d over integers 0..(Q*Q-1)
  +
   >*JJ                      J*J is greater than
       +y/dQy%dQ              sum of y(d / Q) and y(d % Q)
                qQ1          or Q is 1; see below
```

I have to explicitly check for `n = 1`, since my algorithm only checks the corner of the square nearest to the center (and none are covered in `n = 1`).

Answer (score 2):

## Octave <s>(74) (66)</s> (64)

Here the octave version. Basically finding all the vertices within the circle and then finding all the squares with one or more valid vertices via convolution.
64 Bytes:

```
x=ndgrid(-1:2/input(''):1);sum(conv2(x.^2+x'.^2<1,ones(2))(:)>0)
```

66 Bytes:

```
x=meshgrid(-1:2/input(''):1);sum(conv2(x.^2+x'.^2<1,ones(2))(:)>0)
```

74 Bytes:

```
n=input('');x=ones(n+1,1)*(-1:2/n:1);sum(conv2(x.^2+x'.^2<1,ones(2))(:)>0)
```

Answer (score 1):

### R - 64

```
function(n)sum(rowSums(expand.grid(i<-0:n-n/2,i)^2)<n^2/4)+2*n-1
```