# Counting unit squares circle passes through

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry, grid

Write a program or function that given an integer radius *r* returns the number of unit squares the circle with radius *r* centered at the origin passes through. If the circle passes exactly through a point on the grid that does not count as passing through the adjacent unit squares.

Here's an illustration for *r = 5*:

[image: illustration]
<sup>Illustration by Kival Ngaokrajang, found on OEIS</sup>

Examples:

> 0 → 0
>   1 → 4
>   4 → 28
>   5 → 28
>   49 → 388
>   50 → 380
>   325 → 2540
>   5524 → 44180
>   5525 → 44020

Comment: [OEIS - A242118](http://oeis.org/A242118)

Comment: @Luke I just went looking for this, but it seems to use a slightly different definition (at least it doesn't agree on `N = 50`).

Comment: On the other hand, your illustration is clearly taken from https://oeis.org/A242118/a242118_1.pdf (which you should probably cite...)

Comment: @MartinEnder The OEIS numbers are wrong, I have a draft in review as we speak.

Comment: The unit squares will have integer coordinates at their edges, yes?

Comment: @Dennis Yes, although I'm interested what made you think otherwise.

Comment: It seems implied, but the spec doesn't actually say it.

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived at the numbers for the case 50 and up, since they're different from the OEIS and what I'm getting?

Comment: @smls By counting in the bounding square. Make sure that you do not count squares where the circle only touches a corner. The numbers on OEIS are wrong, I have a correction in review right now.

Comment: @orlp: Got it now. May I suggest adding the test-case `5 -> 28`, which *also* has squares where the circle only touches a corner, but is easier to visualize  / reason about than ones with large radii?

Comment: @smls Sure, but that's the illustration :)

Comment: I have a sudden urge to build domes in minecraft again...

Comment: `4 → 28\n5 → 28` um...

Comment: @KritixiLithos Wait until you see 49/50 :)

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48445/20260) with a solid circle.

Comment: Are you a fellow 3Blue1Brown viewer?

Comment: @nitro2k01 Yes :)

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes

```python
f=lambda r,x=0:r-x and-~((r*r-x*x)**.5%1>0)*4+f(r,x+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#DYpBCoMwEEXX9RR/IyTjWBJrFhX0LikSEHRahi6y6tXT2fzHe/xW1jNfrz1Dua5h0bEiyz7@nFMyoeqJ7qmPW/A0D8XZbYi@lbdCcAgCIzJmRrJ9Giw8prR0t48e8oUwihPf/g)

Less golfed (55 bytes) ([TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#HYhBCsIwEEXXeoq/EZIhSlszoIXcxE1EIwU7lVEht49TN@//9woSLu2Z5@stQ8cT6T7S@zs7p3YrVU904F2fUlcWRcUk0CyPu1Pv25pkTV1AHxAD2Hi2sXAcTJiH@CeP281LJ/lAAooT334))

```python
lambda r:8*r-4*sum((r*r-x*x)**.5%1==0for x in range(r))
```

This estimates the output as `8*r`, then corrects for vertex crossings. The result is `8*r-g(r*r)`, where `g(x)` counts the [number of ways to write `x` as a sum of two squares](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64812/20260) (except `g(0)=0`).

If the circle never went through any vertices, the number of cells touched would equal the number of edges crossed. The circle passes through `2*r` vertical gridlines and `2*r` horizontal gridlines, passing each one in both directions, for a total of `8*r`.

But, each crossing at a vertex counts as two edge crossings while only entering one new cell. So, we compensate by subtracting the number of vertex crossings.
This includes the points on axes like `(r,0)` as well as Pythagorean triples like `(4,3)` for `r=5`.

We count for a single quadrant the points `(x,y)` with `x>=0` and `y>0` with `x*x+y*y==n`, then multiply by 4. We do this by counting the numer of `sqrt(r*r-x*x)` that are whole number for `x` in the interval `[0,r)`.

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, 48 bytes

```
4Count[Range@#~Tuples~2,l_/;Norm[l-1]<#<Norm@l]&
```

Looks at the first quadrant and counts the number of grid cells for which the input falls between the norms of the cell's lower left and upper right corners (multiplying the result by 4, of course).

Comment: Another method is `8#-SquaresR[2,#^2]Sign@#&` based on xnor's post

Comment: @miles Oh wow, I had no clue `SquaresR` exists. Feel free to post that yourself (or let xnor post it).

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 72 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(0<n*n-x*x-y*y<2*(x-~y)for x in range(n)for y in range(n))*4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S1OwVYj5n5OYm5SSqJBnVVyaq2Fgk6eVp1uhVaFbqVVpY6SlUaFbV6mZll@kUKGQmadQlJiXnqqRBxaoRBbQ1DL5DxLMAwka6CgY6iiYAJGljoIpkGdsZGrFxVlQlJlXopAGVP0fAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>21</s> <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
R²ạ²Æ²SạḤ×4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@x90aNPDXQsPbTrcdmhTMJD1cMeSw9NN/h/dc7j9UdMa9///DXQUDHUUTHQUTIGkJZACChgbATmmpkYmYNIUAA)

#### How it works

```
R²ạ²Æ²SạḤ×4  Main link. Argument: r

R            Range; yield [1, 2, ..., r].
 ²           Square; yield [1², 2², ..., r²].
   ²         Square; yield r².
  ạ          Absolute difference; yield [r²-1², r²-2², ..., r²-r²].
    Æ²       Test if each of the differences is a perfect square.
      S      Sum, counting the number of perfect squares and thus the integer
             solutions of the equation x² + y² = r² with x > 0 and y ≥ 0.
        Ḥ    Un-halve; yield 2r.
       ạ     Subtract the result to the left from the result to the right.
         ×4  Multiply by 4.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 6, 61 bytes

```perl6
->\r{4*grep {my &n={[+] $_»²};n(1 X+$_)>r²>.&n},(^r X ^r)}
```

#### How it works

```perl6
->\r{                                                    } # Lambda (accepts the radius).
                                                (^r X ^r)  # Pairs from (0,0) to (r-1,r-1),
                                                           #   representing the bottom-left
                                                           #   corners of all squares in
                                                           #   the top-right quadrant.
       grep {                                 }            # Filter the ones matching:
             my &n={[+] $_»²};                             #   Lambda to calculate the norm.
                              n(1 X+$_)>r²                 #   Top-right corner is outside,
                                          >.&n             #   and bottom-left is inside.
     4*                                                    # Return length of list times 4.
```

Answer (score 1):

### AWK, 90 bytes

```
{z=$1*$1
for(x=$1;x>=0;x--)for(y=0;y<=$1;y++){d=z-x*x-y*y
if(d>0&&d<2*(x+y)+2)c++}$0=4*c}1
```

Usage:

```
awk '{z=$1*$1
    for(x=$1;x>=0;x--)for(y=0;y<=$1;y++){d=z-x*x-y*y
    if(d>0&&d<2*(x+y)+2)c++}$0=4*c}1' <<< 5525
```

Just a simple search through quadrant 1 to find all boxes that will intersect the circle.  Symmetry allows for the multiply by 4. Could go from `-$1 to $1`, but that would take a more bytes and be less efficient. Obviously this is not the most time efficient of algorithms, but it only takes about 16 seconds to run the 5525 case on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 74 bytes

```
f n=sum[4|x<-[0..n],y<-[0..n],(1+n-x)^2+(1+n-y)^2>n^2,(n-x)^2+(n-y)^2<n^2]
```

Pretty straightforward, count the number of squares between (0,0) and (n,n) where the bottom left is inside the circle and the top right is outside the circle, then multiply by 4.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 29 bytes

```
Lsm*ddb*4lf}*QQrhyTym+1dT^UQ2
```

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Lsm%2addb%2a4lf%7D%2aQQrhyTym%2B1dT%5EUQ2&input=2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A49&debug=1)

#### Explanation

```
Lsm*ddb*4lf}*QQrhyTym+1dT^UQ2  # implicit input: Q
Lsm*ddb                        # define norm function
 s                             # sum
  m   b                        #     map each coordinate to
   *dd                         #                            its square
                         ^UQ2  # cartesian square of [0, 1, ..., Q - 1]
                               #     -> list of coordinates of all relevant grid points
          f                    # filter the list of coordinates T where:
           }*QQ                # square of Q is in
               r               #     the range [
                hyT            #         1 + norm(T),
                               #                  ^ coordinate of lower left corner
                   ym+1dT      #         norm(map({add 1}, T))
                               #              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ coordinate of upper right corner
                               #     ) <- half-open range
         l                     # size of the filtered list
                               #     -> number of passed-through squares in the first quadrant
       *4                      # multiply by 4
                               # implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Unix utilities, 127 bytes

```bash
c()(d=$[(n/r+$1)**2+(n%r+$1)**2-r*r];((d))&&echo -n $[d<0])
r=$1
bc<<<`for((n=0;n<r*r;n++));{ c 0;c 1;echo;}|egrep -c 01\|10`*4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#NcsxDsIwDEDRvafwECo7UUSCYHJyklKpIgkwucgr5eyhDGxfX3q9IGHNZkI5qjORrD05lMO/vVqdGbESjWMrzxW8gJlqCjMNmk0cbiWltNxXRZQcWNIuWJwj4jcUCFwg8k/yZ2sPbS/w@43XLYbFnnvvly8)

Just go through all the points in the first quadrant, count them up, and multiply by 4.  It can be very slow, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 147 bytes

```
@set/an=0,r=%1*%1
@for /l %%i in (0,1,%1)do @for /l %%j in (0,1,%1)do @set/a"i=%%i,j=%%j,a=i*i+j*j-r,i+=1,j+=1,a&=r-i*i-j*j,n-=a>>31<<2
@echo %n%
```

Somewhat inspired by the AWK and Haskell answers.

Comment: Glad I can somewhat inspire someone :)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES7), 76 bytes

```
n=>4*(G=k=>k<n?Math.ceil((n**2-k++**2)**0.5)-(0|(n**2-k**2)**0.5)+G(k):0)(0)
```

Comment: Can you perhaps shave off a couple of bytes by recursing from `n` down to `0`?

Comment: @Neil I did try but couldn't see a way. Wanted to use just one function but still need to store both `n` radius and `k` iteration and all attempts came out same bytes

Comment: @Neil Ah I see what you are saying about `k<n?...` but I lose out on those bytes reordering at `n**2-k++**2` because the operator precedence is wrong when going in reverse and subtraction is non-commutative so the left side always needs to have `k-1` and needs parentheses. Unless you've found a way?

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the subtraction... maybe you can multiply the whole thing by -4 instead of 4 to work around that? (Although that might still eat up into your saving...)